# Where is Euro Truck Simulator 2's "documents" folder located in OS X?

Tags: macos, euro-truck-simulator-2

I want to add my own radio station to Euro Truck Simulator 2 but I need to get the file in ETS 2's document folder. It isn't in My Documents.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, missed the fact that this is on a Mac instead of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> ~/Library/Application Support/Euro Truck Simulator 2

There you can find *live_streams.sii* file and follow the same procedure for adding your radio stations` streams as on windows.

Please note:

- "~" is your user`s home folder e.g. /Users/USER_HOME_FOLDER
- "Library" folder is hidden by default

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the game on Steam Library->Go to Properties->Local files->Browse local files.